# Recurrent blue screens on Windows 8.1 after installing HAXM

Tags: android, windows-8, android-emulator, haxm

Following testing advices from Google on Android and having installed HAXM I got recurrent blue screens (BSOD) on my Windows 8.1.

- Windows version: 8.1
- HAXM version: 1.0.6

Is there a way to prevent this failure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a quick investigation I didn't find any post on stackoverflow but found the following thread at Intel's Developer Zone:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/475129?page=1

It seems the same error occured on OS X 10.9 and was caused by the GDT.
Following this error report Intel provided a hot fix available here (HAXM version 1.0.7):

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/

Just use `Hotfix for Windows 8.1 only`.

Comment: BTW windows 8.1 is a great OS, people are just too afraid to give it a chance :)

Comment: As the download link is dead, I let a comment on Intel thread in order to have it anew.

Answer (score 0):

I go to those links and all of them are dead links.  How are you guys getting the zip files? I'm logged in and I have accepted the license agreement.  The page shows the windows 8 version and not the windows 8.1 version.  The zip files found in the attachments section which I assume are the hotfix will download, but the zip program with win8.1 says they are empty/corrupt.

Comment: I think this should be a comment. Unfortunately I couldn't find the file to share it again nor any other link to download it. I let a comment on Intel thread asking to fix it.